# Amount using input

Tags: javascript, vue.js, input

I just started my journey in vue, how to make the `input` data take a number into itself, and then display it in a variable, and if you enter 2 times, then add them up.

```
<template>
    <div class="portfel">
        <div class="profile">
            <div class="content__prof">
                <div class="ico__prof"><img src="" alt=""></div>
                <div class="buttom__prof">
                    <input id="txtName" @keyup.enter="addMessage" v-model="myMoney" type="text">
                    <button @click="addMoney">Sum</button>
                </div>
                <div class="value__prof">
                    <div>$: {{myMoney}}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
        data(){
        return{
            myMoney:null,
            dollar:0
        }

    },
    methods:{
        addMomey(){
            this.myMoney.push(this.myMoney) 
        }


    }
}
```

I tried to do it, but it turns out just a direct transfer to a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Check this out](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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):

```js
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      myMoney: 0,
      dollar: 0
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addMoney() {
      this.dollar += this.myMoney
    }
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <input v-model.number="myMoney" />
  <button @click="addMoney">Add
  </button>
  <div>
    dollar: {{this.dollar}}
  </div>
</template>
```

---

If you want to use enter, wrap it in a form and listen for @submit.prevent, [like this](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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):

```html
<form @submit.prevent="addMoney">
  <input v-model.number="myMoney" />
  <button type="submit">Add</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Even without an interpreter, I will personally thank you, now I just have to deal with chart.js, and how to shove them into the VUE.